# Best way to store and read (x,y)->(x,y) dictionary?

Tags: java, c#, dictionary

In c# I store a `Dictionary<Point,Point>` to a file and then in java I read it into a `Map<Point, Point>`. I want to know the best way to store and read the data. I can serialize it into json format, but I feel this uses too much space. I want a solution that minimizes file size and read time into `Map<Point,Point>`. I don't care how long it takes to write to file. Does anyone know a good format (can be totally custom encoding)?

Thanks

Comment: Write the numbers? Points are extremely simple, it takes less code than the words used in your question to write them to a file.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: It feels like you have very specific requirements and particular shape of the input data - but neither is explained in the post. So far answer that suggest to write 4 integer per item (text/binary) seem to satisfy question *as posted*, but clearly it is not what you are looking for based on comments.

Answer (score 2):

The most compressed file format would be binary, but that has it's own problems since you're writing in C# and reading in Java. The simplest file format that everybody can understand (C#, Java, Humans), is a CSV file. In your case, a CSV file with 4 numbers per text line, separated by commas.

Let's say your dictionary/map has the following mappings:

```
(1,1) -> (2,3)
(1,3) -> (3,7)
```

Then the CSV file would be:

```
1,1,2,3
1,3,3,7
```

The file doesn't have to define that it's Point to Point mappings, it just needs to carry the data in a format that can be correctly loaded back into a map.

Comment: I think I can do better than that. Right now, I'm not even storing the key point. I am only writing the value point in an ordering that iterates through all the x,y points in order from (0,0) to (w-1,h-1) seperated by commas. If a specific x,y point doesn't exist as a key, I don't write anything, so its like two commas. And then I merge all sequence of commas of length 2 or more into like `x30` if there were 30 commas. And there is no new line characters. This gives decent results, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: I think the only way to reduce file size even more is to write the numbers in binary. I assume the number of missing points is less than 50%, otherwise writing the key/value pairs would actually be smaller when writing in binary, unless you "compress" sequences of missing points.

Comment: "Writing in C# and reading in Java" should not be a problem.  If these points are integers, the format of a binary integer is language-independent; if they're doubles, they'd be written in an IEEE standard format which is also language-independent.  The byte ordering would be the only consideration.

Comment: For empty points, perhaps [NTFS Sparse file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codedebate/archive/2007/12/18/6797175.aspx) could help